# trackpad and wifi broken after rollback to kernel 5.8.0-44 or booting to focal-proposed 5.8.0-49

Tags: wireless, 20.04, kernel, touchpad

I have a Lenovo Yoga 730 running Ubuntu 20.04.  A recent wacom driver issue prompted me to try an older kernel so I installed 5.8.0-44 with

```
apt install linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic
apt install linux-headers-5.8.0-44-generic
```

but when I boot to this kernel, neither the trackpad, touch, stylus nor the wifi work at all.  Is there more I need to install to get this old kernel to fully work?

The same thing happens when I try to install 5.8.0-49 from focal-proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please also install:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-44-generic
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Reboot.

Comment: perfect, thanks.